# how to create a Kirby like system for a 2d plaformer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Im new to game developing and i was working on a 2d platformer project where i want to code a script to allow the player to steal the enimes ability like in kirby games but a lot simpler for a prototype, for inistance a enemy that can double jump, if the player kills it then presses a button he gains the ability to double jump

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the enemy script have an `enum` that determines the element or the power e.g.

```cs
public enum Elements {
  None,
  Water,
  Fire,
  Air,
  Stone
}
```

You can add as many elements as you wish. Then when a player sucks up an enemy, the player reads the enum and then applies it to himself via like `element = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>().element;` and then you can update the looks of the player. Then in your update function or where ever, you can make the player behave differently based on his element

TLDR;

1. Create an enum and put in onto your enemy and the player
2. When an enemy is sucked in or stuff like that, make the player's element the enemies element
3. (can be skipped) If the element is None, don't apply, like in the games
4. Modify player behaviour by checking the enum in some if statements

[Enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)